# An MDB File is created programmatically from ADOX extension. Is this file size abnormally large?

Tags: c#, ms-access, dataset, export

I used the code in this forum to create a method to export DataSet object to MDB file:
http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=93599

My DataSet contain only one table, 5 columns with about 100k rows. The size of MDB file that produced is 50 MB. I wonder if it is too abnormally large?

Please let me know if you have better method of exporting DataSet to MDB file for smaller file size.

Comment: Have you tried running a compact and repair on the file? 50MB does seem a little big for that amount of records. The can happen though if you've inserted and deleted numerous times.

Comment: How do I do it programmatically?

Comment: I  notice that after I manually open it using Microsoft Access 2010, the file size is automatically reduce to only 6.5 MB (?), I bet that it is because the file was "running compact" and "repair" by itself?

Comment: I'm not aware that these files compact and repair themselves unless you've turned that option on in Access. Even if you have it turned on, the compact and repair happens when you close Access, not when you open it.

Comment: What are the size of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50MB * 1024KB/MB * 1024byte/KB = 52428800 bytes.

52428800 / 100000 rows / 5 columns/row = ~105 bytes per column.

Depending on how you defined your columns, this may not be out of line... especially when we have yet to consider any indexes, page size and padding, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to Repair and Compact the MDB File programmatically:

```
    private static void CompactAndRepairMDB(string FilePath)
    {
        string FileName      = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath);
        string FileName_Temp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath) + "_CompactAndRepair";

        string FilePath_Temp = FilePath.Replace(FileName, FileName_Temp);

        JRO.JetEngine oJetEngine = new JRO.JetEngine();

        string SourceConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                      "Data Source=" + FilePath + ";" + 
                      "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;";

        string DestConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                    "Data Source=" + FilePath_Temp +";" +
                    "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;";

        //Compact the database (makes a new copy)
        oJetEngine.CompactDatabase(SourceConn, DestConn);

        //Overrite the old new
        File.Copy(FilePath_Temp, FilePath, true);

        //Delete Temp File
        File.Delete(FilePath_Temp);
    }
```